# Soundcloud: Detect missing localStorage support and inform the user

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, soundcloud, browser-feature-detection

Recently, I had trouble accessing the Next Soundcloud. No matter which url I tried, the general error page appeared, telling me something went wrong and recommending modern browsers.

The browser console said that the app failed when accessing `window.localStorage`:

```
TypeError: localStorage is null
```

Indeed, I had `dom.storage` globally disabled in my Firefox config. There may be other users out there who are using a modern browser but have `dom.storage` disabled and thus may feel left alone with this generic error page.

I'd appreciate something like an alert box that informs the users about missing support for *that particular* feature. Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VL5Mx/1/embedded/result/) with `dom.storage` disabled/enabled. It's implemented in a few minutes but makes the user experience way better, I think.

So, are there already some kind of specific error pages being planned for Soundcloud?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because SO is not Soundcloud’s bug tracking or feature request system.

Comment: Right, sorry for the inconvenience. I mailed the Soundcloud support directly, we'll see what comes out. :)

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question, it's not entirely clear to me if you want to check for `localStorage` support, or specificity check if someone has the `dom.storage` setting enabled/disabled in Firefox.

Checking for localStorage support is fairly easy:

```
function hasLocalStorage() {
    return window.localStorage && !!window.localStorage.getItem
}
```

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a fairly popular library which contains a bunch of tests, and some polyfills.

As for checking `dom.storage`, no, that will never be possible. It would be a serious security/privacy problem if a website would be able to read settings from the browser. The last few years browsers have moved to providing *less* information to servers, not more.
See [this page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fingerprinting) for example.

The best you can do is check for localStorage support, and if it's not available, display a help page with instructions for all the browsers.

Comment: I'm sorry, confusion was not intended. This question is actually addressing the Soundcloud dev team or anyone who is involved in their front-end development. The feature detection itself was not my concern (viewed the fiddle?), but whether the Soundcloud guys are going to add concrete error pages.

Comment: Maybe I got it wrong, the [SoundCloud dev support](http://developers.soundcloud.com/support) pointed me here to ask my question. ;)

Comment: @schwarztee Right. Carefully re-reading your question, I see you're trying to address a specific SoundCloud problem/bug/feature. This sort of question is so unexpected, I missed that. I can't venture a guess why a support rep from soundcloud would send you here, this site is a question & answer site for programmers.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. The developers' support page is a bit misleading, they just want to have discussion about their api functions on SO. I mailed the Soundcloud support directly, we'll see what comes out. Anyway, thanks for your time.